# Multiple declaration of angular2 routes necessary?

Tags: angular, routes

I'm trying to get my application to respond to the following urls:

```
/agent
/agent/login
/agent/travel
```

I can get it to work if I use the following route declarations (in a single file):

```
{ path: 'agent', component: AgentPage },
{
  path: 'agent', component: AgentPage,
  children: [
    { path: 'login', component: AgentLogin },
    { path: 'travel', component: AgentTravel }
  ]
},
{ path: '', component: AgentPage },
{ path: '**', component: NoContent }
```

If I remove the first route definition /agent stops working and I hit the NoContent component...

This is my agentPage.template.html:

```
<div>agentPage</div>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

I really don't understand why I need two identical declarations apart from the children and would like to be able to run it in a more cleanly fashion (ie w/o the first route definition)

Can someone clarify this to me?

TIA

Answer (score 0):

Did you try with empty path as first child ?

```
{
    path: 'agent', component: AgentPage,
    children: [
        { path: '', component: AgentPage }
        ...
    ]
}
```

Comment: Yes I did but then I get my agentPage.template.html displayed twice - will update question